# I cannot use a variable in program functions

Tags: tkinter

There is a program with a GUI, the code is written in python 3.7 in PyCharm. 
**The problem**: you cannot use the variable degree in the functions encrypt() and create_mask().
I'll make it easy for connoisseurs to help, because I've got zero in python programming myself.
I would be very grateful for your help.
*Program code:*

```
import os
from tkinter import
from tkinter import filedialog as fd
from tkinter import messagebox as mb


global degree1


def variable():
    l = encrypt_st.get()
    if I == 1:
        degree1 = 1
    elif I == 2:
        degree1 = 2
    elif I == 3:
        degree1 = 4
    elif I == 4:
        degree1 = 8
    return degree1


def encrypt(degree1):

    f = fd.askopenfilename(title="Select text file")
    text = open(f, 'r')
    d = fd.askopenfilename(title="Select stegocontainer")
    start_bmp = open(d, 'rb')
    encode_bmp = open('encode_bmp', 'wb')

    text_len = os.stat(f).st_size
    img_len = os.stat(d).st_size
    if text_len >= (img_len * degree1 / 8) - 54:
        mb.showerror("It is not possible to hide the data select a larger container")
    return

    first54 = start_bmp.read(54)
    # print(first54) # show the first 54 bytes
    encode_bmp.write(first54)

    text_mask, img_mask = create_masks(degree1)
    while True:
        symbol = text.read(1)
        if not symbol:
            mb.showerror("Can't read the file")
            break
        symbol = ord(symbol)
        for byte_amount in range (0, 8, degree):
            img_byte = int.from_bytes(start_bmp.read(1), sys.byteorder) & img_mask
            bits = symbol & text_mask
            bits >> 8-degree
            img_byte |= bits
            encode_bmp.write(img_byte.to_bytes(1, sys.byteorder))
            symbol <<= degree


def decrypt():
    pass


def create_masks(degree1):
    text_mask = 0b1111111111[enter image description here][1]
    img_mask = 0b1111111111

    text_mask <<= (8 - degree1)
    text_mask %=256
    img_mask >>= degree1
    img_mask <<= degree1
    return text_mask, img_mask


root = Tk()
root.title
root.geometry("400x90")
button1 = Button(text = "Hide data", command=encrypt)
button1.place(x=1, y=1)
lab1 = Label(text="Select degree of coding:")
encrypt_st = IntVar()
encrypt_st.set(0)
var1 = Radiobutton(text="1", value=1, variable=encrypt_st, command=encrypt)
var2 = Radiobutton(text="2", value=2, variable=encrypt_st, command=encrypt)
var3 = Radiobutton(text="4", value=3, variable=encrypt_st, command=encrypt)
var4 = Radiobutton(text="8", value=4, variable=encrypt_st, command=encrypt)
lab1.place(x=100, y=1)
var1.place(x=100, y=20)
var2.place(x=135, y=20)
var3.place(x=170, y=20)
var4.place(x=205, y=20)
root.mainloop()
```

Error code: 
 File "C:\Users\1\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\tkinter__init__.py", line 1883, in **call_**
    return self.func(*args)
TypeError: encrypt() missing 1 required positional argument: 'degree1'

Translated with www.DeepL.com/Translator (free version)

Comment: English only on this site. => https://ru.stackoverflow.com

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

1. The use of `global` in the global scope has no effect. You should declare a variable as `global` when it is inside an inner scope, like a function or a class definition. To fix this, you should add `global degree1` to any function that uses your `degree1` variable. As a side note, the use of `global` is kind of frowned upon, as there are better ways to accomplish the effect of a "shared" variable. The most common way is to use a class approach.
2. `tkinter` doesn't provide an out-of-the-box way of passing arguments to commands on an event. I can think of two ways to work around this, however. The first (and probably most used) is to use a `lambda` which returns a handle to the function. This is done by

```py
var1 = Radiobutton(text="1", 
                   value=1, 
                   variable=encrypt_st, 
                   command=lambda: encrypt(degree1))
```

The other way is to use a partial function, which you can create when using the [**`functools`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html) library.

```py
from functools import partial
partial_encrypt = partial(encrypt, degree1)
# partial_encrypt is now a partial object which will call
# encrypt(degree1) when called. We can pass this as a command
# to your tkinter widget.

var1 = Radiobutton(text="1", 
                   value=1, 
                   variable=encrypt_st, 
                   command=partial_encrypt)
```